# Set node size (sphere volume) based on hub centrality using D3 and ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, data-visualization

I'm working from vasturiano's web component to represent a graph data structure in a 3-dimensional space using a force-directed iterative layout. It uses ThreeJS/WebGL for 3D rendering and either d3-force-3d or ngraph for the underlying physics engine.

https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph

I would like to set the node size (sphere volume) based on a hub centrality score defined in the dataset. I can see that `nodeVal([num, str or fn])` could be used to do this but I don't know how to define this properly.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples something like

```
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
  (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
    .graphData(gData)
    .nodeVal( node => node.hubscore);
```

Or if using a string is enough

```
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
  (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
    .graphData(gData)
    .nodeVal("hubscore");
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't work otb. Hubscore is not defined as a usable property. I'm starting out with JavaScript and I don't know how to write this functionality in.

I used `.nodeVal('group')` and ended up having to manually change the json dataset to get the project working--this is not the most efficient process and I would really like to be able to set this property here.

Comment: @xuaero: how is Hubscore defined, you say it is in the dataset